# Scrape a webpage and save as static page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to save the static version of a [loaded webpage contents](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html).
So, for doing that I am using `kora.selenium` in Colab. The code is,

```
#!pip install kora
from kora.selenium import wd
wd.get("https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html")
page_source = wd.page_source

with open("page_source.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(page_source)
```

But the extracted HTML is changing after loading the webpage. How Can I save this
static HTML with page content and images?

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://pypi.org/project/pywebcopy/

It uses lxml to parse the elements and requests to fetch the content. You can do the same with BeautifulSoup (Which has lxml as one of its parsers) but it is a lot of job to check for all meta contents and download it.

Your example downloads 17MB into /dist/cnbc-copy

```
from pywebcopy import save_website
save_website(
url="https://www.cnbc.com/2022/01/03/5-ways-to-reset-your-retirement-savings-and-save-more-money-in-2022.html",
project_folder="/dist/cnbc-copy",
project_name="cnbscopy",
bypass_robots=True,
debug=True,
open_in_browser=True,
delay=None,
threaded=False
)
```